# Reading button's background image

Tags: android

I'm trying to read a button's background image, this is what i'm trying:

```
  ImageView btn_java1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.background);
  int draw = R.drawable.ic_launcher;


    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View var1) {

        if (btn_java1.getBackground().equals(draw)){
            a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            a.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        }
    });
```

But it's not working and I can't see the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need to define a int variable;all you need to do is write below code in your if condition:

```
if (btn_java1.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.ic_luncher).getConstantState())
```

i dont remember now but check above code with or without `getConstantState()` and see if its work...

**EDIT**

for api 21 above you can use this method:

```
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
  public static boolean checkImageResource(Context ctx, ImageView  imageView, 
    int imageResource) {
boolean result = false;
if (ctx != null && imageView != null && imageView.getDrawable() != null) {
    ConstantState constantState;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        constantState = ctx.getResources()
                .getDrawable(imageResource, ctx.getTheme())
                .getConstantState();
    } else {
        constantState = ctx.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource)
                .getConstantState();
    }

    if (imageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == constantState) {
        result = true;
    }
}

return result;
```

}

Comment: Thanks but 'getDrawable' is deprecated, "cannot resolve method getDrawable"

Answer (score 0):

getBackground() returns a Drawable. draw is an integer. So comparing them is not going to go well....

Maybe you could use:

```
 Drawable draw= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_luncher);
```

Hopefully you realize "luncher" is not "launcher".